# I need calendar similar to this

Tags: input, calendar

I need a calendar with the same functionality as this one:

[calendar](http://www.luk3.yoyo.pl/cal/)

I want date in input box and by clicking on the individual values ​​(month, day, year) date was changed, and I was able to choose date from the drop down list.

Does anyone know of something similar?

For some reason I can not use this calendar

Comment: Are you wanting to make a calendar or just download it somewhere

Comment: @CSharpDev, i just want to download it. I'm not so god at js to type somethink like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new version avaiable at 
http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/convenient-javascript-calendar-date-picker/